Python subprocess get the handle after popen
I am using Windows 10.
I want to get the "handle" (or hWnd) of the process after using subprocess.Popen.
What can I do?

In order to obtain a window handle (hWnd), you need to use an additional library pywin32 to use the Windows API functions.
import subprocess
import win32api
import win32con
import win32process

# Start a process
process = subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe"])

# Get the process ID (PID)
pid = process.pid
print(f"Process ID (PID): {pid}")

# Get the process handle
handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)

# Get the window handle (hWnd) associated with the process
hWnd = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle)
print(f"Window Handle (hWnd): {hWnd}")

